# Python BS4.element.tag how do I execute click() on this

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, click

I've got a ResultSet object of 
`bs4.element module` 
which is a set derived from this:

```
def unexpanded_league_tables(flash_page):
    unexpanded_elements = flash_page.find_all("span",{"class":"expand-league"})
    return unexpanded_elements
```

Which is called via :

```
find_unexpanded = unexpanded_league_tables(parsed_page)
```

where parsed_page is a parsed BeautifulSoup:

```
def parse_page(driver):
    return BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'lxml')
```

which resolve thus for type :

```
type(find_unexpanded[0])
Out[205]: bs4.element.Tag
```

I am trying to do find_unexplained[0].click() 
but this is returning 'NoneType' which I take to mean there is no method .click() for Tag. 
What do I use to click on the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was correct in assuming it was not something I could do with that element type. I found out a unique property in the element that was returned (an id) and did a driver.find_element_by_id on it :

```
        unexpanded_span_element = driver.find_element_by_id(tables_to_expand[len(tables_to_expand)-1]['id'])
        unexpanded_span_element.click()
```

Comment: where did `driver` come from? is it a selenium driver?

Comment: chromedriver.exe

Comment: so you have `chromedriver.exe` in your python file? I don't get it. like `open('chromedriver.exe')`?

Comment: driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Development\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')